# Python. Как выписать списком все даты начиная с определенной

Tags: python, datetime

Нужно выписать список все даты начиная с 2015-01-01
до вчерашнего дня (к примеру 10.08.2020)

```
data_1 = [20150101, 20150102, 20150103, 20150104, 20150105, 20150106, 20150107, 20150108, 20150109, 20150110, 20150111...20200811]
```

Comment: А что мешает это сделать в цикле while?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

cur = date(2015, 1, 1)
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
delta = timedelta(days=1)
dates = []
while cur <= yesterday:
    dates.append(cur.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
    cur += delta
print(dates)
```

https://ideone.com/gWW0BB

Также можно воспользоваться библиотекой pandas:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas as pd

yesterday = (date.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(pd.period_range(start='2015-01-01', end=yesterday, freq='D'))
```

https://ideone.com/xxzOqx