# Создать список дат между списком интервалов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

У меня есть датафрейм, в котором имеются интервалы дат

```
   start         end
0  2020-02-14    2020-02-16
1  2020-03-08    2020-03-10
2  2020-03-17    2020-03-19
3  2020-04-12    2020-04-19
4  2020-05-01    2020-05-03
```

Мне нужно создать список дат, которые находятся в интервале между start и end в каждой строке

Например, для первых двух строк это будет : 2020-02-14, 2020-02-15, 2020-02-16, 2020-03-08, 2020-03-09, 2020-03-10

Я пробовал решить это через цикл, но он не заработал

```
list_of_dates = []
for i in range( len(df) ):
    start = df['start'][i]
    end = df['end'][i]
    new_date = pd.date_range( start, end, freq='d' )
    list_of_dates[i].append(new_date)
```

Comment: В каком формате даты в фрейме excel_datetime или строковые?

Comment: приведите в вопросе результат, который вы хотите получить. Вам нужен один список со всеми датами, входящими во все интервалы?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1164823/235436

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас даты имеют типа datetime, то это сделать довольно просто (я перевел сразу date_range в список):

```
df["range"] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x["start"], end=x["end"], freq="D")
                       .date.tolist(), axis=1)
```

тогда df у вас будет:

```
       start        end                                              range
0 2020-02-14 2020-02-16               [2020-02-14, 2020-02-15, 2020-02-16]
1 2020-03-08 2020-03-10               [2020-03-08, 2020-03-09, 2020-03-10]
2 2020-03-17 2020-03-19               [2020-03-17, 2020-03-18, 2020-03-19]
3 2020-04-12 2020-04-19  [2020-04-12, 2020-04-13, 2020-04-14, 2020-04-1...
4 2020-05-01 2020-05-03               [2020-05-01, 2020-05-02, 2020-05-03]
```